# Make Area Page-able

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, paging, uipagecontrol

How Can I make the green area of the screen shot of my app be able to scroll with the paging animation and page indicators?I would like for me to add more icon-buttons to it with keeping the header the same size.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Have you looked at UIScrollView?

Comment: It's also a shame to waste so much real estate on the header ... why not leave that to the splash image, or a bg image etc...?  If the app is dominated by the header and you have to scroll to get to the primary functionality, it might not be the best design ...

Answer (score 0):

First you need a scroll view and your view has to be inside of the scroll view. 
Then you need to enable paging on the scroll view

```
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
```

> If the value of this property is YES, the scroll view stops on multiples of the scroll view’s bounds when the user scrolls. The default value is NO.

If you want to have page indicators you need to use `UIPageControl`which you will have to manage yourself as far as I know. You could always check after scrolling (see `UIScrollViewDelegate` ) which page you are on based on the `contentOffset` property of the scroll view.

Comment: I can't get it to page or scroll

Comment: Is your content size (scrollView.contentSize) set properly?